# Editorconfig configuration for unity methods, fields with serializefield attribute

Tags: unity-game-engine, roslyn, editorconfig

[image: Unity Methods]

[image: Fields with SerializeField]

Is there any way to suppress these suggestions on unity event methods and fields with `[SerializeField]`? I'm currently using roslyn analyzer on vscode.

[image: Roslyn Analyzer]

Configure editorconfig under `[*.unity.cs]` and put .unity.cs extension to every single unity scripts is the only way I found.

Supress these suggestions only on Unity event methods and fields/properties with `[SerializeField]` attribute

Comment: Never used VSCode .. maybe there is an extension for this. For VisualStudio and Rider this is covered via the according IDE unity packages and/or extensions in the IDE ... [Visual Studio Code Editor package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.ide.vscode.html) should be installed in your project by default afaik but if not install it via package manager